# How to create key value JSON response in perl script with MYSQL data

Tags: mysql, json, perl

I have a perl script which does some query and return response in JSON format. But the return JSON is only array of values.

This is Perl Script

```
my $sql_query = "SELECT * from table_categories";
my $statement = $db_handle->prepare ($sql_query) or die "Couldn't prepare query '$sql_query': $DBI::errstr\n";  
$statement->execute() or die "SQL Error: $DBI::errstr\n";  

my @loop_data = ();

while (my @data = $statement->fetchrow_array())
{
    push(@loop_data, @data);
}   

my $json;
$json->{"entries"} = \@loop_data;

my $json_text = to_json($json);
print $json_text;
```

and response is like this

```
{
    "entries": [
        [
            "1",
            "Salt and Sugar",
            "/images/salt_sugar.png",
            "7"
        ],
        [
            "2",
            "Tea and Coffee",
            "/images/tea_and_coffee.png",
            "6"
        ],
        [
            "3",
            "Spice and Pickles",
            "/images/categories/spice_pickles.png",
            "7"
        ],
        [
            "4",
            "Pooja Needs",
            "/images/categories/pooja-needs.png",
            "9"
        ],
        [
            "5",
            "Dry Fruits",
            "/images/categories/dry_fruits.png",
            "7"
        ]
    ]
}
```

But I want the response like this:

```
{
"entries": [
    [
        "id": "1",
        "name": "Salt and Sugar",
        "image": "/images/salt_sugar.png",
        "rank": "7"
    ],
    [
        "id": "2",
        "name": "Tea and Coffee",
        "image": "/images/tea_and_coffee.png",
        "rank": "6"
    ]
]
}
```

How to achieve that?
What changes i need to do in PERL script?
Please help.

Answer (score 4):

If you specifically don't have need to loop over every row, I'd prefer to use `selectall_arrayref` with slicing:

```
my $json;
my $sql_query = "SELECT * FROM table_categories";
$json->{entries} = $db_handle->selectall_arrayref( $sql_query, {Slice => {} } );

my $json_text = to_json($json);
print $json_text;
```

So you get keys too and code is more compact and clear.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `fetchrow_hashref` instead of `fetchrow_array` to receive a hashref where the column names are used for the property names using the code below.

```
my @loop_data = ();

while (my $hashref = $statement->fetchrow_hashref())
{
    push(@loop_data,$hashref);
}
```

More information: https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchrow_hashref